# Is it Possible to do my MiniCMS Project in ASP.Net or I use PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, content-management-system, project

Which one is best to go ahead and useful?

Comment: In the end this is a religious debate. Both platforms have CMS implementations why not pick your favorite platform and use one of the existing cms implementations?

Answer (score 1):

Totally depends on your programming experience. You should pick the language you feel most at 'home' during coding.

I have some PHP experience and more ASP.Net/C# experience. So I'd pick ASP.Net/C#, because I'm more a friend of having a single DLL that acts as connection between your websites and the information entered into the CMS. With a PHP framework that acts as connection between your website and the database you will probably have more files than just one. If all of them are in same folder it is probably ok, but think about updating them if they are in a seperate folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your own CMS as a small framework for your websites and you want to develop your own functionality, **PHP** will be a better choice since it is only an *scripting language*, But **ASP .NET** is itself a *framework*! And a frame means a closed area, but full of ready functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer PHP , keeping in mind the low  Hosting Costs for  hosting  your CMS  website . you can use PHP ,Mysql , and any open source  Apache  locally for  development and low cost hosting on linux based hosting .   There are many development tools available for PHP too .

The list of  PHP Frame Works are available here http://www.phpframeworks.com/